# Android: Recover image bitmap from representation as decoded string

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am makinga  web service call to fetch a jpeg image, I store it as String in order to be the Value of some Json field (web service return Json...). The web service himself retrieve the image from URL, so in overall I have insdie my web service:

```
InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageWebServiceURL).openStream();
String imageAsStringReadyForJson = getStringFromInputStream(in);

private String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then in Android I try to do vice versa:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(stringFromJson.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
Bitmap photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
imageView.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);
```

The result: Below the ImageView I have TextView, if I comment out `imageView.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap)` the TextView displayed at top of the activity view. After I do call `imageView.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap)`, I see the text moves down to free space for the image, but the place remains empty (activity white background...).

Where is the bug here?

Comment: the image is not in base64 ?

Comment: What you mean? How can I know? I have url that returns the image... Base64 is because I use UTF-8?

Comment: I see the image is binary  but you use UTF-8 and json ??
I think the way to put in json is base64 or something
Or use binary and nothing of UTF-8 or JSON

Comment: You cannot convert an input stream from an image to a String. Or use StringBuilder for that. If you want the image in a String then you should base64 encode it to a String.

Comment: 'Where is the bug here?'. There is no bug. Your code is completely wrong. On server side. On Android side.

Comment: @greenapps Why you not putting what you said as answer? (gain reputation etc..)